# How can i use dynamic variable in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RouletteRecRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public RouletteRecDto findOne(RouletteRecCriteriaDto request) {

        TypedQuery<RouletteRecDto> query = em.createQuery(
                "select new opgg.weba.JamPick.dto.RouletteRecDto(i.id, i.headerImage)" +
                        " from IndieApp i join i.genres g where g.description in :request group by i.id", RouletteRecDto.class)
                .setParameter("request", request);

        RouletteRecDto result = query.getSingleResult();

        return result;
    }

}
```

```java
@Data
public class RouletteRecCriteriaDto {
    private List<String> genreList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
RouletteRecCriteriaDto request = new RouletteRecCriteriaDto();
request.setGenreList(List.of("RPG, ACTION"));

RouletteRecDto rouletteApp = rouletteRecRepository.findOne(request);
```

I initialized request value to list of String.
And I want to search data which contain "RPG" or "ACTION" in genre column.
However, if i use `:request`, it doesn't work. (If i use `g.description in ('RPG', 'ACTION')` instead, it work)
How can i use dynamic value in JPQL? (The value of a variable or the number of variables can change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pass list of string in your query, replace the object `RouletteRecCriteriaDto` with `List<String>`.

```
List<String> list = reqeust.getGenreList();
TypedQuery<RouletteRecDto> query = em.createQuery(
            "select new opgg.weba.JamPick.dto.RouletteRecDto(i.id, i.headerImage)" +
                    " from IndieApp i join i.genres g where g.description in :request group by i.id", RouletteRecDto.class)
            .setParameter("request", list);
```

or

```
TypedQuery<RouletteRecDto> query = em.createQuery(
                "select new opgg.weba.JamPick.dto.RouletteRecDto(i.id, i.headerImage)" +
                        " from IndieApp i join i.genres g where g.description in :request group by i.id", RouletteRecDto.class)
                .setParameter("request", request.getGenreList());
```